# How to make background gradient on page refresh in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, ionic6, ionic-react

[image: 1]

I have a task to do a page refresh in the application, the problem is that the background of my application is a gradient, not a static color, ionContent perceives a gradient in the background, but when I refresh the page, a block with an ionPage background appears at the top of the screen , in the screenshot, I specifically highlighted this area so that you understand what I'm talking about, tell me how to avoid this content break with the page

It is very difficult to find an answer to a similar question on the Internet, since the ionic is quite young and not many people have encountered this, I perfectly understand the essence of the problem, but I cannot come to a solution

Answer (score 0):

> a block with an ionPage background appears at the top of the screen

This is correct, this is a visual cue for the user that there is a refresh functionality available. You cannot remove this. But you can make it smaller by using the pullMax and pullMin properties available. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/refresher#pullmax